# XUL attaching events to anchors added with javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, addeventlistener, mutation-events

I'm writing a firefox extension that adds event listeners to all the anchor tags on a page. Essentially I have:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { myExtension.init(); }, false);

var myExtension = {

    init: function() {
    var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");  
    if(appcontent)
        appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myExtension.onPageLoad, true);  
    },

    onPageLoad: function(event) {
        var doc = event.originalTarget;
        var anchors = doc.getElementsByTagName("a");
        //attach event listeners
    }
}
```

This works for most of the tags on the page.  The problem is that tags added with javascript don't get the event listener attached. I've tried redefining createElement:

```
//in the onPageLoadFunction
var originalCreateElement = doc.createElement;
doc.createElement = function(tag) {
    if (tag != "a"){
        return originalCreateElement(tag);
    }
    var anchor = originalCreateElement("a");
    anchor.addEventListener("mouseover", myInterestingFunction, false);
    return anchor;
}
```

and I've tried adding a DOM insertion listener

```
//in the onPageLoadFunction
function nodeInserted(event){;
    addToChildren(event.originalTarget);
}

function addToChildren(node){
    if (node.hasChildNodes()){
        var nodes = node.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
            addToChildren(nodes[i]);
        }
    }
    if (node.nodeName == "a"){
        anchorEvent(node); //adds event listeners to node
    }
}

doc.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", nodeInserted, false);
```

but neither work.  How can I get references to these anchor objects so I can add listeners to them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adding "event listeners to all the anchor tags on a page" dynamically is hard to do efficiently. You have two choices:

1. Periodically poll the page for anchor tags (like `jQuery.live()` does)
2. Use [DOM mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference/DOM_Events) (DOMNodeInserted, etc.)

The former has an obvious performance impact. Using mutation events has a hidden performance cost: if any mutation events are added for a document, Gecko takes a slower path in its DOM code, so all DOM manipulation works slower.

Why not use `addEventListener` to set up a listener on some top-level element (or even the whole window) and check if the target is an anchor? You could use a capturing listener to make your listener be called before the default action occurs.

Comment: I've tried the DOM mutation event as I noted above, and it didn't seem to work.  Periodically polling the page gets to be a problem for an extension because users may have many tabs open at once, and all would be polling at some interval.  It slows down alot.

Comment: So I don't know why mutation listener doesn't work for you; I'd need to construct a testcase to play with it to find out. Are you sure the listener doesn't fire? Maybe try registering it on some element deeper in the DOM tree? /// In any case I think the last solution I suggested is better, did you try it?

Comment: I tried polling the page 1.5 secs after it loads, and that does work to get most of the links.  I also tried it polling the page every three seconds, but that slowed things down too much.  So the polling does work, thanks. I was just hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Can you read what I write? :) Try the last suggestion in the main reply and if that doesn't suit your needs, do try to debug the mutation listeners problem, it should work.